How can I change the size of icons in ModernCV?
Is there a way to change the size of icons (phone, mail, social etc.) in ModernCV, other than redefining each of them? If so - how?
I'm using the classic theme which uses fontawesome icons, with pdfLaTeX.
MWE:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}  

\moderncvstyle{classic}                            

\name{John}{Doe}
                             
\born{4 July 1776}                                 

\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}                
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}                              
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                       

% Social icons
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}                   
\social[xing]{john\_doe}                           
\social[twitter]{ji\_doe}                           
\social[github]{jdoe}                              
\social[gitlab]{jdoe}                              

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\end{document}


A MWE which produces the current (unwanted) icon size would be helpful in providing suggestions as to making smaller icon sizes that are clearly identifiable. Otherwise the answer to the question of the title is: yes.

@Leucippus Edited the question with a MWE and changed the title to include "HOW can I do it".

The icons macros (e.g. \faHandPointUp) from the fontawesome5 package are defined with the \faPreselectedIcon macro. Since moderncv print the icons in a group, you can patch \faPreselectedIcon to also select a font size
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}  

\moderncvstyle{classic}                            

\name{John}{Doe}
                             
\born{4 July 1776}                                 

\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}                
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}                              
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                       

% Social icons
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}                   
\social[xing]{john\_doe}                           
\social[twitter]{ji\_doe}                           
\social[github]{jdoe}                              
\social[gitlab]{jdoe}    

\AddToHook{cmd/faPreselectedIcon/before}{\Huge} % or any other font size command...                            

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\end{document}


I think it is preferable if you'll ask the maintainer of moderncv to add some customization options to the class (instead of hard coding the icon size for example) than start patching many things...

Great, that's just the solution I was hoping would be possible. Thanks!
And just for the record, I wanted the icons smaller :)
Yes I have quite a lot of patching, more than I intended, when I finish my submission I'll make some feature requests in their github.
